# How to create a folder and copy all it's files to new WordPress plugin folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, file-upload, directory

So the situation is that WordPress are often installed in limited rights or not perfectly configured web hostings and it's impossible to create directories, copy or move files, or copy or move whole directory to new location via Php code functions.
I have issues when:

> 1. `rename(.., ..);` gave - 'do not have required permission' error,
> 2. `CHMOD(..., 0777);` did not make directory writable either,
> 3. `mkdir(..., 0777);` did not created writable dirs under web users, but created 0755 dirs under apache users (1000), where Php scripts from WordPress engine were unable to write in.

I'm looking for a best working solution (or WorkAround) to copy all files from one to other folder when regular rename(..), chmod(..) and mkdir(..) Php functions are not working as expected.

Comment: meagar, if you can provide a better solution for the problem - you are welcome. I provided my best.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I made a solution - a class that works and provided it's code in the answer of this topic. I hope this will save you a half-day as now it saves for me.

I wrote a class that solves the problem and I believe this will help to many of you, who develops plugins for WordPress and do have to make actions with files.

Usage example is bellow:

```
$uploadDir = wp_upload_dir();
$fromFolder = ABSPATH."wp-content/plugins/old-cool-plugin/gallery"
$toFolder = $uploadDir['basedir']."/cool-plugin-gallery";
$copied = WordPressFileManager::copyFolder(fromFolder, $toFolder);
if($copied)
{
   echo 'All old folder files copied successfully to new directory';
} else
{
   echo 'Your server setup is so bad, that it is unbeatable even with perfect scripts';
}
```

And class code is bellow:

```
class WordPressFileManager
{
    public static function createWritableDirectory($paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash)
    {
        // Create an upload dir if not exist
        $newDirectoryExists = TRUE;
        if (!file_exists($paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash))
        {
            // The mkdir doesn't work in WordPress setup on regular servers (DirectAdmin+Ubuntu based etc.)
            //$uploadDirectoryExists = mkdir($paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash, 0777, TRUE);
            $newDirectoryExists = wp_mkdir_p($paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash);
        }

        // Check if folder iss writable
        $newDirectoryWritable = FALSE;
        if($newDirectoryExists)
        {
            if(is_writable($paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash) === FALSE)
            {
                chmod($paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash, 0777);
                if(is_writable($paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash))
                {
                    $newDirectoryWritable = TRUE;
                }
            } else
            {
                $newDirectoryWritable = TRUE;
            }
        }

        return $newDirectoryWritable;
    }


    /**
     * Because copy($moveFolderAndAllFilesInsideFrom, $paramToFolder) - does NOT work in this WordPress setup (because of CHMOD rights),
     * so we need a workaround function - and this is the main reason why we have a function bellow, which DOES WORK!
     * @param $moveFolderAndAllFilesInsideFrom
     * @param $paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash
     */
    public static function recurseCopy($moveFolderAndAllFilesInsideFrom, $paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash)
    {
        $sourceDirectory = opendir($moveFolderAndAllFilesInsideFrom);
        while (FALSE !== ( $file = readdir($sourceDirectory)) )
        {
            if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' ))
            {
                if ( is_dir($moveFolderAndAllFilesInsideFrom.'/'.$file))
                {
                    static::recurseCopy($moveFolderAndAllFilesInsideFrom.'/'.$file, $paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash.'/'.$file);
                } else
                {
                    copy($moveFolderAndAllFilesInsideFrom.'/'.$file, $paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash.'/'.$file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($sourceDirectory);
    }

    /**
     * Copy folder and all it's files from it's old location to new location
     * @param $copyAllFilesFromFolderWithoutEndSlash
     * @param $paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function copyFolder($copyAllFilesFromFolderWithoutEndSlash, $paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash)
    {
        $copied = FALSE;
        if(file_exists($copyAllFilesFromFolderWithoutEndSlash))
        {
            $toDirectoryIsWritable = static::createWritableDirectory($paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash);
            if($toDirectoryIsWritable)
            {
                // NOTE: copy() does NOT work in this WordPress setup (because of CHMOD rights)
                //$copied = copy($moveFolderAndAllFilesInsideFrom, $paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash);
                static::recurseCopy($copyAllFilesFromFolderWithoutEndSlash, $paramToFolderWithoutEndSlash);
                $copied = TRUE;
            }
            // DEBUG
            //echo "<br />[{$copyAllFilesFromFolderWithoutEndSlash}] SOURCE FOLDER (TO MOVE FILES FROM IT) DO EXISTS, ";
            //echo "destination folder is writable: "; var_dump($toDirectoryIsWritable);
        } else
        {
            // DEBUG
            //echo "<br />[{$copyAllFilesFromFolderWithoutEndSlash}] SOURCE FOLDER (TO MOVE FILES FROM IT) DO NOT EXISTS";
        }

        return $copied;
    }
}
```